# Why Ubuntu 12.04 shows me AHCI error?

Tags: 12.04, bios, ahci

I installed 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the computer won't boot. This is a Dell Precision Workstation 690 computer, which has a BIOS dated in 2006. It was running `Red Hat EL 4` quite well. The Ubuntu installation proceeded without any problems. After installing Ubuntu 12.04, it has the following messages:

```
Controller Bus #00, Device#1F, Function#02: 00 Ports

No device found

AHCI BIOS not installed
```

I tried switching from `AHCI` to `ATA` in the BIOS, which eliminated these particular messages, but it still wouldn't boot.

What can I do to get this computer to boot with 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I got mine working by disconnecting all hard drives except the one for the OS (actually, my OS drive shows as a Dell Virtual drive as it is two drives mirrored by the Dell HBA) and re-installed with the Ubuntu *server* version thinking the server version may have better RAID controller support.

In the end, I think the problem was GRUB had not been installed properly (for whatever reason).

After installation, I reconnected my other hard drives and everything is working fine.  To get my desktop back, I did a 'apt-get install ubuntu-desktop'.

I still get the same message re: no device found, AHCI BIOS not installed, but the message quickly goes by and the system continues to boot.